# Что мне дает программа no-ip ?

Tags: ip, ddns, dns

Что мне дает программа no-ip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеет смысл пользоваться, если у тебя динамический IP адрес. Программа отслеживает изменение IP адреса и присваивает его домену, который ты укажешь на сайте программы. Таким образом ты всегда сможешь найти свой компьютер в сети интернет. Проблемы могут возникнуть, если у тебя "серый IP" (т.е. на одном IP адресе несколько компьютеров) в таком случае необходимо настроить маршрутизатор (или обратиться к провайдеру) и обращаться к своему ПК примерно так [vasya.no-ip.com:5800](http://vasya.no-ip.com:5800)

Answer (score 0):

[vasya.no-ip.com:5800](http://vasya.no-ip.com:5800) ну так конечно не красиво лучше сделать редирект в 5800 на 80